# Java substring get value after a string and before the next space

Tags: java, substring

I have a string like

> 231 AVE BLDG 2 UNIT 234'

I need to do a substring that is after `BLDG` and before the next space. i.e `2`

Another example is:

> 231 AVE BLDG 2'

Here the substring must pick the value after `BLDG` and till the end of the string. i.e `2`

For the second case i have written the logic as below:

```
address.substring(address.indexOf(" BLDG ") + 6, address.length());
```

But need help with the first case.

Comment: What is the expected result in both cases?

Comment: 2 is the expected result in both the cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
 (?:BLDG\s)(\w*)(?:\s\S)?
```

Captures `2` for both cases

**Use:**

```
String patternString = "(?:BLDG\\s)(\\w*)(?:\\s\\S)?";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
Matcher matcher = patter.matcher(address);

if(matcher.find())
    String substring = matcher.group(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

For your first case you could use a regex like so:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "231 AVE BLDG 2 UNIT 234";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("BLDG (.*?) ");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); //2
    }
  }
}
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/FME8/0)